# How can I send an array from iOS app and create multiple mysql rows using php?

Tags: php, ios, mysql

So in my iOS app the following information is stored in `NSUserDefaults (latitude, longitude, number of seconds since epoch)` in the form of an `NSMutableArray` of `NSStrings`.

Each index in the array consists of a **latitude value**, **longitude value**, and a **seconds since epoch time value**. Since this array can be more than 1 in size, my goal is to transfer each index of the array into my database (each index of information is a row in my database table).

I could send out a web request for each index but I assume that is a very bad way to do this.

**Question:** My problem is I am not very familiar with php. I am guessing the way to go about doing this is splitting the information up inside of the php? And then some how loop the mysql INSERT command? I am not quite sure how to do this.

**iOS**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableArray *reportedSightings = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[defaults objectForKey:@"reportedSightings"]];
    // All objects in reportedSightings are NSString with the following format: "latitude,longitude,secondsSinceEpoch"
    // EXAMPLE: "43.993950,-77.720637,1432359000" (without the quotations)

    NSString *allInformationString = @"";
    for(int i=0; i<reportedSightings.count; i++)
        allInformationString = [allInformationString stringByAppendingString:reportedSightings[i]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/addInformation.php?information=%@", allInformationString]];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]; 
}
```

**addInformation.php**

```
<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","database");
    mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");


    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }


    $information = $_GET["information"];

    $latitude =
    $longitude =
    $secondsSinceEpoch =


    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO InformationReported (latitude, longitude, secondsSinceEpoch) VALUES (''$latitude', '$longitude', '$secondsSinceEpoch')");
    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```